# Amplitude and Phase of FFT

Tags: r

I have a sound function I am trying to break up into sines/cosines. So I resorted to Fast Fourier Transformation. By using the `fft(y,inverse=FALSE)` function I was able to convert the time domain of the sound into the frequency doman. The output is complex. I read that in order to convert this output which is in imaginary form and weed out the necessary information, which are the amplitude and the phase of `A(v)cos(2*pi*v+P)`, one must use the `abs()` of the output to get the amplitude; however I am having difficulty finding the R function that gets us the phase. In MATLAB, the `angle()` function returns the phases of the FFT. What is the respective function in R to find the phase??

**Update**

Thank you for the suggestions guys; still expericieng an issue. I am running FFT on a simple function to test to see if it works. My function is `y=cos(2*pi*(seq(0,10,by=.01)*(1/5)+7.5)`.
So the frequency is 1/5 with a phase shift of 7.5.

```
y=cos(2*pi*(seq(0,10,by=.01)*(1/5)+7.5)
fty=(y,inverse=F)
plot(abs(fty),xlim=c(0,10),type="l")
angle=atan2(Im(fty), Re(fty))
> angle[3]
[1] 1.222766
```

When I plot the series, the amplitude is peaking at a frequency value of 3 and the angle function (which should give me my phase at the frequency at which amplitude peaks at) is giving me a phase of 1.2. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Phase of 7.5 (radians) will be reduced module 2pi. If you subtract 2*3.14 from 7.5 you get about 1.2 as you found.

Comment: Thank you Floris. What about the frequency? In the output I had a frequency bin of 3, what operation adjusts the value to 1/5?

Comment: The first bin contains the DC component; the third bin contains the frequency that fits exactly twice. You have `2*pi*seq(0,10,by=0.01) * (1/5)` which we can rewrite as `2*pi*seq(0,2,by=0.002)`. Thus you can get exactly two waveforms (10 / 5 = 2), and you see the peak in bin 3 as expected. To go the other way, (maxBin - 1) / maxTime = (3 - 1) / 10 = 1/5 . Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find that the `atan2` function does what you want. You would give it the imaginary and real parts of the value, since the prototype is `atan2(y, x)`. So you could do:

```
angle = atan2(Im(value), Re(value));
```

Comment: Should be `Im` and `Re`

Comment: Thank you for your help Floris!! The output from the `fft()` is of the form `a+bi` so it includes the real and the complex function. How do I parse `a` from the `b` in the output vector? Are the `im` and `re` actual functions in R? If so, which package?

Comment: `Im` and `Re` (sic) are in base R, and they are the answer to your question.  `x <- complex(real=2:3,imaginary=1:2); print(x); Im(x); Re(x)`

Comment: My bad - they should be `Im` and `Re` as @MatthewLundberg and Ben Bolker pointed out - not `im` and `re`. So yes - `Re(fftOutput)` should give you the `a` values, and `Im(fftOutput)` the `b` values.

Comment: Thank you for your help Matt and Floris. I was able to compute the angle of the FFT but the values don't make sense. Please see the intial post for an update.